# Python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple. Caesar Cypher Decoder

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am working on writing a decrypter for Caesar Cyphers that won't require the user to input the amount the message was changed by. It will then look for common letter occurrences and print the ones with the most matches down to the lest matches. It will print them all fine. Just without an order. My aim was to save the decoded messages and the amount of occurrences to a 2d array. Yet I have reached a problem with this. It returns this error when I try to edit the array. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import sys
import time
from time import sleep as s
import random
import collections

global c1, message, letters, array, i, output

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lletters = letters.lower()
length = len(letters)
space = " "
length1 = len(space)

c1 = int(0)

check = ["hi", "ing", "ai", " i ", "oo", "e ", "as", "wh", "er", "th", "re", "or", "eir", " if ", "en", "ph", "zz", "ll", "ff", "ei", "ie", " a ", "qu", "eu", "au", "ue", "ca"]
output = [25,1]

message = input("Enter the thing you want to decrypt. ")

def decrypt():
    global c1, letters, message, list1
    decrypted = ''
    for counter in range(1,26):
        decrypted = ""
        c1 = int(counter)
        p = int(counter - int(1))
        for chars in message:
            if chars in letters:
                num = letters.find(chars)
                num -= c1
                num = num%length
                decrypted += letters[num]
            elif chars in lletters:
                num = lletters.find(chars)
                num -= c1
                num = num%length
                decrypted += lletters[num]
            elif chars in space:
                decrypted += space
        ho = int(0)
        h1 = int(0)
        for i in range(len(check)):
            h = check[i]
            if h in decrypted.lower():
                output[p,1] = int(h1)
                h1 = h1 + int(1)
                output[p,1] = int(h1)
                if ho == int(0):
                    ho = int(1)
                    print(str(output[p,2]))
                    print(decrypted)

decrypt()
```

Comment: You are indexing the array on lines 47, 49, and 52 with `[p,1]` or similar. This is not valid syntax as you are, as the error says, trying to index an array with a tuple. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I am going to save each decrypted message to the list then use the number to change the order of the decrypted messages to have the ones with the most amount of the check array in be printed first. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in the list slicing syntax. It is l[start:finish] not l[start, finish]. change this line:

```
print(str(output[p,2])
```

to:

```
print(str(output[p:2])
```